# how to create username , address and details with firebase authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I know how to create email and password authentication with firebase but that will create only email and id but how do i add name and more detail to that id for instance how I call user.getdisplayname?

Here is my code for creating authentication email and password

```
bv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                final ProgressDialog pros=ProgressDialog.show(Register.this,"please wait..","registerring..",true);
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                pros.dismiss();
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,"sucsseful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i=new Intent(Register.this,login.class);
                }else {
                    Log.e("ERROr",task.getException().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

If you say to create database as well, then how I link it to the user authentication?

```
private FirebaseUser UserDetaill = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `UserProfileChangeRequest` like this

```
UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                .setDisplayName("XXX YYYY")
                .setPhotoUri(URI)
                .build();
UserDetaill.updateProfile(profileUpdates);
```

**USING TASKS**

```
 FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .continueWithTask(new Continuation<AuthResult, Task<? extends Object>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<? extends Object> then(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) throws Exception {
                    UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                            .setDisplayName("XXX YYYY")
                            .setPhotoUri(URI)
                            .build();
                    return task.getResult().getUser().updateProfile(profileUpdates);
                }
            });
```

Comment: good man thank you and is there is away to create user authentication and name at the same time and if i use setDisplayName("XXX YYYY") that will change the loged in user only? thank you

Comment: i think you can't you need to create the user and then update it, it will change the data of the user directly

Comment: thank you i think i put all inside abutton it should work in 1 click i am testing it thank you will confirm

Comment: well i updates my answer using tasks so you can create a user and update it directly

Comment: Thank you all works perfect without your last line return task.getResult().getUser().updateProfile(profileUpdates);